# How to paste xml tag in this forum?

Tags: xml

I have a doubt in pasting xml tag here. How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

When you post a chunk of XML, make sure to highlight those lines in the editor here, and then click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to properly format them - that's all there is to do!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your text editor, select all and hit tab a couple of times. (if your IDE supports that)

Stack Overflow uses tabbed in content in the response as code.